# Rotating body around a point Box2D Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, box2d, point

I have a problem when rotating a triangular image like a radar detecting enemies.

```
b2Body *body;
CCSprite *actor;



if (b->GetType() == b2_kinematicBody && myActor == [loader spriteWithUniqueName:@"radar."]){

        radar = b;
        radarSprite = myActor;
    }
```

It is a kinematic Body made with LevelHelper, and I want to rotate it. So I need it to rotate around a static point, and repeat the movement backwards. Since it is a Body and not a Sprite, I don't know how to make it to **rotate around the top point**.

I have an idea, but I'm not sure.
 What about if I rotate the CCSprite and move the Body to sprite.position? Is it possible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I update position and rotation of box2d bodies acording to theirs sprites:

```
// Box2d updates.
// We set position of b2Bodies according to their sprites.
_world->Step(delta, 10, 10);
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext())
{
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        GameObject *sprite = (GameObject *)b->GetUserData();
        b2Vec2 b2Position = b2Vec2(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO,
                                   sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);

        float32 b2Angle = -1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(sprite.rotation);
        b->SetTransform(b2Position, b2Angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. I'm going to try it but I think it will work! THANK YOU VERY MUCH